# Water coming in around foundation when it rains

Tags: water

My home was built in the 1980s.  I live in Oklahoma.  Last month with all the rains I started getting water coming in and soaking carpets  I have a slab foundation.  I pulled the carpet up no cracks. I thought the water was coming in where the air conditioner lines and hot water lines run into the house. I sealed all of that but when it rained again I got more water.  There is a rock garden outside of that part of the house. Any suggestions

Comment: Did you make any changes to the area where the water is penetrating?

Comment: Tester101. Not in three years.  That's when I put the rock garden in. And I simply put rock on top of the ground

Comment: Can you post a picture of the house and where the water came in? one from the inside and one from the outside would be ideal.

Comment: Any closure here?  Was there a sprinkler system?  When you pull up the carpet you should see some "wet" right?  Maybe dry it out with air and see where it's coming back in to give you a clue, GL!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your gutters. Every time I end up with water in my basement it is the result of some issue with my gutters. I have a lot of old trees around my house and during certain times of the year it is impossible to keep them clean (I know I need guards). If they back up the water pours over the sides and then builds up near the basement walls and eventually seeps inside.

Also, make sure the downspouts are all still attached and if needed get some extensions to send the water further away from the house.

Also, check the grade of the area surrounding the foundation. Make sure that there is a least a small slope away from the house. If the rock bed is too high - or if you have some kind or plastic underneath to prevent weeds it might be preventing the water from draining properly.

Comment: There are no gutters.  And I was thinking that the rock bed might be causing some of the problem. I do have a weed barrier under them.  I will make the rock garden so it isn't by the foundation any more.  But the water does seem to be coming in through the same spot where the lines run into the house.   Who would you call to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sump pump? If so it may be because the sump pump is not functioning properly and not pumping the water from your foundation out, which leads to water seeping onto your floor.

Comment: No there is no sump pump. I have lived there since 2001 and never had this problem before.

Comment: No not that I have ever seen. And lived there since 2001

Comment: You only see sump pumps associated with basements. Since your house is just on a slab, like most houses in Southern part of the U.S., you wont have one.

Comment: My house doesn't have a basement and it has a sump pump.

Answer (score 0):

With a slab, your only option is grading the soil around the house exterior.  It should be highest right next to the foundation and slope downward away from the house.  Further away, there should be drainage leading away from the yard so that the water can't accumulate and overrun the slope up to the house.  Normally this is done with soil grade, drains, drainpipe, ditches, pumps, etc. depending on the likelihood of flooding and the expense of construction.

For a more definitive answer, we'd need to see a grade schematic for your house and the surrounding area.